# How should I check if the password is weak or good After applying PasswordStrengthBar?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, password-storage

I'm using **PasswordStrengthBar**   `import PasswordStrengthBar from 'react-password-strength-bar';`
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-password-strength-bar

I want to display a message when the confirmation button is clicked and the password is weak ..
How should I check if the password is weak or good?

```
<input type="password" className="form-control" value={this.state.newPassword} onChange={this.passwordOnChange} id="pwd" />
<PasswordStrengthBar   password={this.state.newPassword}   />
```

Comment: You can use ```onChangeScore ```  prop or access to ```state.score``` via reference, directly .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to github source of this package

https://github.com/lannex/react-password-strength-bar/blob/master/examples/src/Home.js

you can call a function whenever score changes with `onChangeScore` attribute

```
 <PasswordStrengthBar
        password={this.state.newPassword}
        onChangeScore={score => {
          console.log(score);
        }}
      />
```